# send object from application_rake to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a task in application_rake. The lines that matter are:

```
family = Family.find(114)
SysMailer.deliver_feedback_memo(emails_str,"escorter", family)
```

In the SysMailer model i try to write the name of the family like this:

```
puts family.name
```

name is an attribute of family (for sure!!!)

But when I run:

```
rake the_task
```

I get an error:

```
rake aborted!
missing attribute: name
```

Why? is there a problem to send an object from rake to a model?

**UPDATE:**

After struggling with the issue, I tried not to pass the object, but pass only the family.id to the model like this:

```
SysMailer.deliver_feedback_memo(emails_str,"escorter", **family.id**)
```

(The asterisks are just to show the change).

Then in the model I created a method that takes this argument:

```
def some_method(emails, type, **family_id**)
  family = Family.find(family_id)
  puts family.name
```

And it works.

So my question remains. Is there a problem to pass an object with rake?

Answer (score 0):

There definitely shouldn't be a problem passing objects via method calls -- even if from a rake task.

If the `family.name` statement was actually what was failing I'd expect you'd see a message more like:

```
undefined method :name for #<Family>
```

So it sounds like you may be looking at the wrong line of code (i.e. it may be the fault of something else in the code). A missing attribute error sounds more like a mass-assignment problem.

Have you tried running the rake task with the `--trace` option?

```
rake the_task --trace
```

This may help identify the problem, either way.

Comment: Yes, I did try the trace, but with no luck. Well, I did try not to pass the object and then in the model I created a new family object from the family.id, and it worked. Does it help to undersatand the problem?

Comment: Interesting. Can you update your question to show, in code, what you're saying worked here? I don't quite follow.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, thanks. It certainly sounds as if there's a problem marshaling the Family object between the 2 method calls. That's interesting...